# How to extract next integer in an arbitrary position in string?

Tags: c++, string, stream, cin, getline

My code is below, I'm working on a simple text editor. The user needs to be able to input the following format:

> **I n** 
>   //where n is any integer representing the line number.

I used a switch statement below to see what the first character they typed is, but in **case 'I'** (insert) and **case 'D'**(delete) I need to be able to extract the integer they typed after that.

**For example:**

> D 16   // deletes line 16
>   I 9    // Inserts string at line 9
>   L      // lists all lines

I have tried a few different things but nothing works smoothly so I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
void handle_choice(string &choice)
{   
    int line_number;

      // switch statement according to the first character in string choice.
    switch (choice[0]) 
    {

    case 'I':

       // code here to extract next integer in the string choice

      break;

    case 'D':

      break;

    case 'L':

      break;

    case 'Q':

      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
```

I tried a few different things like getline() and cin <<
but I can't get it to work properly in case the user doesn't input the line in that specific format and I was wondering if there is a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// This function takes the whole input string as input, and
// returns the first integer within that string as a string.

string first_integer(string input) {
   // The digits of the number will be added to the string
   // return_value. If no digits are found, return_value will
   // remain empty.
   string return_value;
   // This indicates that no digits have been found yet.
   // So long as no digits have been found, it's okay
   // if we run into non-digits.
   bool in_number = false;

   // This for statement iterates over the whole input string.
   // Within the for loop, *ix is the character from the string
   // currently being considered. 
   for(string::iterator ix = input.begin(); ix != input.end(); ix++) {
     // Check if the character is a digit.
     if(isdigit(*ix)) {
         // If it is, append it to the return_value. 
         return_value.push_back(*ix);
         in_number = true;
     } else if(in_number) {
         // If a digit has been found and then we find a non-digit
         // later, that's the end of the number.
         return return_value;
     }
   }
   // This is reached if there are no non-digit characters after
   // the number, or if there are no digits in the string. 
   return return_value;
}
```

Within your switch statement, you would use it like this:

```
case 'I':
     string number = first_integer(choice);
     // Convert the string to an int here.
```

Comment: While I'm really thankful for your answer, I'm a novice at best and I'm having a hard time following what's going on in your code and therefore how to implement it.

Comment: I added some comments to explain what it's doing and what to do with the function.

Comment: Very thorough explanation of this function, I understand everything now.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a function, I would do something like this:

```
char command; 
int line; 
cin >> command >> line; //put the first character in command, and the next one in line
```

If you do want to use a function, you should convert the string to a stringstream. Stringstreams let you assign values to variables much like cin, handle all conversion, tell you when input failed, and skip whitespace.

So in you function, you would first create a stringstream

```
stringstream inputStream (choice); //make a stringstream from the input string
```

Next, input the stringstream values into the variables like above:

```
char command; 
int line; 
inputStream >> command >> line;
```

Now, command contains the letter, and line contains the number. However, sometimes there is no line number, just the command. In that case, the second input will fail. Conveniently, stringstreams let you check for this:

```
inputStream >> command >> line; 
if(inputStream.fail()) { //input to line failed, probably because there was no number
/*your code for when there is no number*/
}
```

You might have to include additional checks.

Comment: Though I chose the other answer this also works and I ended up using it elsewhere in my code, so thank you @DarvishKamalia